# Paginated report Multiple Parameters with Nulls and DAX

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I am trying to build a paginated report with some basic knowledge. It is connected to Power BI Service dataset. I want to use it as embedded in regular Power BI report where I could select parameters from slicer and export as PDF (the main reason to use this terrible mechanism). It was fine until i wanted to use blanks and multiple parameters -> same as in BI in a slicer. Whata nightmare and as -always easy task - impossible to do. I would appreciate any support

I just want to use slicers in regular POWER BI report for parameters for paginated report but as in regular report i would like to have an option to use multiple values and blank value as well.